# Add a new Jakarta EE specification to existing project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, jetbrains-ide, java-ee-8

When creating new project in *IntelliJ IDEA* you can choose the specifications you need in your project:

[image]

But I want to add new specification (like JSF) **to currently existing project without adding it manually into pom.xml file** (because of boilerplate files the wizard creates automatically like web.xml or faces-config.xml and etc.).

How can I do that by *IntelliJ* **wizard**?

Answer (score 0):

- Install and enable [Jakarta EE: Server Faces ​(JSF)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18583-jakarta-ee-server-faces-jsf-) plugin and other Jakarta plugins if needed
- Right-click on a project root directory in [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html)
- Select `Add Framework Support...`
- Choose the needed components and click OK

Comment: Your solution added items such as `Icefaces`, `Openfaces`, `Primefaces`, `Richfaces` ... but not JSF. And also I can see JSF when creating a new project without installing any plugin (you can see it in image in my question)

Comment: Try using the latest IDE build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download (221.5591.52) https://prnt.sc/oTek-EOYMWZU

Comment: My IDE is *IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)*. In *Eclipse* I just do it by right click on the project and select desired facelets (JSF, JPA, ...).